# How to add HTML comment in tinymce editor in rails project

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tags, tinymce, comments

I am using the tinymce editor for one of my rails app.
I need to add HTML comments (`<!-- -->`), but it's not able to save the HTML tag as comment.

Please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the comment markers in the bracket. Just add a backslash before the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the tinymce plugin named `code` (visible as 'html'-button in the tinymce UI) in order to insert comments. If you enter them as text inside the editor they will be treated as text.